# trigger a send from python script

Tags: python, orange

hi i wish to be able to trigger a send with a thread launched in an Orange python script but i can't figger how.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import Orange.data
import time

#The thread intialisation 
class CustomThread(QThread):
    finished_signal = pyqtSignal()
    send_signal = pyqtSignal(Orange.data.Table)

    def __init__(self, in_data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.in_data = in_data

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 11):
            print(f"Compteur : {i}")
            #the signal for the function in the main thread who is suposed to trigger the send out_data
            self.send_signal.emit(self.in_data)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.finished_signal.emit()

def out_data1(data):
    new_data = Orange.data.Table(data)  
    new_data.X[0][0] = 1.0 
    print(f"Type de l'objet Orange.data.Table : {type(new_data)}")
    print(f"Nombre d'instances : {len(new_data)}")
    #here the signal is supposed to start 
    out_data = new_data 
    return(out_data)


    
iris = Orange.data.Table("iris")
my_thread = CustomThread(in_data=iris)
my_thread.finished_signal.connect(lambda: print("Le thread est terminé."))
my_thread.send_signal.connect(out_data1)
my_thread.start()
```

i wish that the data out would be retrigered with each iteration in the thread but it only happen the first iteration